# Downloading an Android app with an existing expansion file prompts downloading a large file?

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I have a 10MB app with a 100MB expansion file. If I try to download the app, but the expansion file already exists in my device, why does the Play Store tell me that it's downloading a large file?

The download is still 10MB, but most users would think that the Play Store downloads the expansion file every time I update the app. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you downloading an app which is not currently installed, despite having an expansion file left over on the device from a previous period of installation?  Or are you downloading an update to an app which currently has a previous version installed?

Comment: An update to an app. If it's a new install it's intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You should upload your expansion file like path version, and download it programmatically if expansion file does not exists in device, if exists then ok